# Wine on Ubuntu - Copy to clipboard needs 2 CTRL-Cs

Tags: wine, clipboard

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on 64bit and wine 4.0.2
Clipboard functionality is fine between native linux and wine programs and vice versa. 
But copying from one wine program to another requires at least two CTRL-C (or selecting the Copy command from the menu). If I press CTRL-C only once, CTRL-V (pasting) does nothing for me.
This occurs including the windows software Total Commander, HeidiSQL and EditPad Pro.

Somewhere I read that there is a primary and secondary clipboard buffer, and that might the source of the issue here. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04, worked fine on 18.04

Comment: Same problem here. Ubuntu 20.01, Wine 5.0 wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1).

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine/+bug/1856708) I also have this problem with ubuntu 20.04 and wine 5.0.